# Need to update service provider in wso2 using soap request : SAML2 Web SSO Configuration details

Tags: wso2, soapui, wso2-identity-server

I need to update service provider in wso2(v5.7.0) using SOAP Request. I saw the soap request using soapUi tool of wso2 service provider services.But did not find the correct tag to update the SAML2 WEB SSO CONFIG
. I need to update following saml2 web sso config details using Soap req:

Issuer * I know can't update this one but the other we can.

Assertion Consumer URLs *

Default Assertion Consumer URL *

NameID format

Enable Response Signing

Enable Signature Validation in Authentication Requests and Logout Requests

Enable Single Logout
SLO Response URL
Single logout response accepting endpoint
SLO Request URL
Single logout request accepting endpoint
Enable Attribute Profile
Include Attributes in the Response Always
Enable Audience Restriction
Audience

Enable Recipient Validation
Recipient

Enable IdP Initiated SSO
Enable IdP Initiated SLO
Enable Assertion Encryption

Need to update the above details using soap request except the issuer one.

This is soap request .  I saw using soapui from following link
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Using+the+Service+Provider+API#UsingtheServiceProviderAPI-updateApplication

Comment: I see that you've duplicated the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63881773/how-to-update-the-service-provider-in-wso2is-version-5-7-saml2sso-configuratio  I've answered there. Shall we remove this and continue the discussion there?

Comment: sure you will remove this one. thanks for replying @Nipun Thathsara