# How to update the service provider in wso2is version 5.7 - saml2sso configuration details

Tags: soap, soapui, wso2-identity-server

currently working on wos2IS version 5.7 in our org as identity servier. we are doing all the wso2 related services  like tenant creation , user store, service provider using soap request using spring boot. I am facing one problem here to update service provider saml2sso config detail using soap request. I have read the document of wso2 as well as saw the ServiceProviderServices of wso2 of Soap Request using SoapUI tools but didnot find the suitable soap request for the same. could any body help me on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **IdentitySAMLSSOConfigService** for this. The WSDL contract is available at https://localhost:9443/services/IdentitySAMLSSOConfigService?wsdl URL. (Make sure that you have the `<HideAdminServiceWSDLs>false</HideAdminServiceWSDLs>` in the `carbon.xml` file to access the WSDL files)

These SAML configurations are being stored in the registry, as registry collections and properties. Therefore, changing these should be possible using registry admin services as well.

However, this is a two step process where you first create the application using **IdentityApplicationManagementService** service. And then use the **IdentitySAMLSSOConfigService** method as below to change the SAML configurations. (Below sample is only for the latter step.)

**Sample request**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd"
               xmlns:xsd1="http://dto.saml.sso.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
    <xsd:addRPServiceProvider>
        <xsd:spDto>
            <xsd1:assertionConsumerUrls>https://localhost:9443/assertionURL</xsd1:assertionConsumerUrls>
            <xsd1:attributeConsumingServiceIndex></xsd1:attributeConsumingServiceIndex>
            <xsd1:certAlias></xsd1:certAlias>
            <xsd1:defaultAssertionConsumerUrl>https://localhost:9443/assertionURL</xsd1:defaultAssertionConsumerUrl>
            <xsd1:digestAlgorithmURI>http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha512</xsd1:digestAlgorithmURI>
            <xsd1:doEnableEncryptedAssertion>false</xsd1:doEnableEncryptedAssertion>
            <xsd1:doSignAssertions>true</xsd1:doSignAssertions>
            <xsd1:doSignResponse>true</xsd1:doSignResponse>
            <xsd1:doSingleLogout>true</xsd1:doSingleLogout>
            <xsd1:doValidateSignatureInRequests>true</xsd1:doValidateSignatureInRequests>
            <xsd1:enableAttributeProfile>true</xsd1:enableAttributeProfile>
            <xsd1:enableAttributesByDefault>true</xsd1:enableAttributesByDefault>
            <xsd1:idPInitSLOEnabled>false</xsd1:idPInitSLOEnabled>
            <xsd1:idPInitSSOEnabled>false</xsd1:idPInitSSOEnabled>
            <xsd1:idpInitSLOReturnToURLs></xsd1:idpInitSLOReturnToURLs>
            <xsd1:issuer>testissuer</xsd1:issuer>
            <xsd1:loginPageURL></xsd1:loginPageURL>
            <xsd1:nameIDFormat>urn/oasis/names/tc/SAML/1.1/nameid-format/emailAddress</xsd1:nameIDFormat>
            <xsd1:nameIdClaimUri></xsd1:nameIdClaimUri>
            <xsd1:requestedAudiences>https://localhost:9443/audiences</xsd1:requestedAudiences>
            <xsd1:requestedRecipients>https://localhost:9443/recipients</xsd1:requestedRecipients>
            <xsd1:signingAlgorithmURI>http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256</xsd1:signingAlgorithmURI>
            <xsd1:sloRequestURL>https://localhost:9443/singleLoguoutRequest</xsd1:sloRequestURL>
            <xsd1:sloResponseURL>https://localhost:9443/singleLoguoutResponse</xsd1:sloResponseURL>
        </xsd:spDto>
    </xsd:addRPServiceProvider>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: In case of update the above details will go as addRPServiceProvider  or it should be anything else just have doubt

Comment: how i will merge the above soap req with updateservice provider soap req

Comment: I want to do in one soap req